# .JS Function will continue executing, with wrong values

Tags: javascript

As you can see this is actually a simple application, however the code seems to continue using the first `IF` statement even though it isn't correct/relevant anymore.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Slideshow">
   <img id="Slide" src="images/Slide01.jpg" width="600px" height="450px">  
   <button type="button" onClick="SlideShowTimer()">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<!--Closing Slideshow-->
```

**JS**

```
function SlideShowTimer() {
    var IMG1 = "images/Slide01.jpg";
    var IMG2 = "images/Slide02.jpg";
    var IMG3 = "images/Slide03.jpg";
    var Slide = document.getElementById('Slide').src;

    if (document.Slide === document.IMG1) {
        document.getElementById('Slide').src = "images/Slide02.jpg"; * * * //keeps executing this even once the value has actually changed to the value of 'IMG2'***  
    } else if (document.Slide === document.IMG2) {
        document.getElementById('Slide').src = "images/Slide03.jpg";
    } else if (document.Slide === document.IMG3) {
        document.getElementById('Slide').src = "images/Slide01.jpg";
    } else {
        alert("Something Went Wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think `document.Slide` contains the right html element ?

Comment: Why are you even prepending `document.` before your variable names?

Comment: strangely enough i have thought the same thing, however without 'document.' i would get no results at all, which i personally find strange myself since i came across this issue for the first time myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because

```
 document.getElementById('Slide').src
```

returns an absolute path.

EDIT:

```
function SlideShowTimer() {
var IMG1 = "images/Slide01.jpg";
var IMG2 = "images/Slide02.jpg";
var IMG3 = "images/Slide03.jpg";
var Slide = document.getElementById('Slide');

if (Slide.src.indexOf(IMG1) >= 0) {
   Slide.src = "images/Slide02.jpg"; 
   alert('1');
} else if (Slide.src.indexOf(IMG2) >= 0) {
    Slide.src = "images/Slide03.jpg";
   alert('2');
} else if (Slide.src.indexOf(IMG3) >= 0) {
   alert('3');
    Slide.src = "images/Slide01.jpg";
} else {
    alert("Something Went Wrong");
}
```

}

Comment: any other suggestions other then using the absolute path?

Comment: You need to set equal absolute pathes in both the IMG1/2/3 and src. Or you can just parse the path from src to start from -- images/. Or try to use indexOf() method.

Comment: just so i understand correctly, we are losing the variables, and writing it out plain:
 `code``
    if (document.getElementById('Slide').src == "images/Slide01.jpg") {
    document.getElementById('Slide').src = "images/Slide02.jpg";;
} else if (document.getElementById('Slide').src == "images/Slide02.jpg") {
    document.getElementById('Slide').src = "images/Slide03.jpg";
} else if (document.getElementById('Slide').src == "images/Slide03.jpg") {
    document.getElementById('Slide').src = "images/Slide01.jpg";
} else {
    alert("Something Went Wrong"); `code``

Comment: Not quite sure what is your point. But try to comment this code for now and test .indexOf() method like this: document.getElementById('Slide').src.indexOf('images/Slide01.jpg');

Comment: document.getElementById('Slide').src returns path that is different from what you're expecting. And you're expecting 'images/Slide01.jpg'. That is way when you compare these pathes they are different.

Comment: using .indexOf() results in nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
if (Slide == IMG1) {
    document.getElementById('Slide').src = IMG2;
} else if (Slide == IMG2) {
    document.getElementById('Slide').src = IMG3;
} else if (Slide == IMG3) {
    document.getElementById('Slide').src = IMG1;
} else {
    alert("Something Went Wrong");
}
```

Comment: Jumps straight to = alert("Something Went Wrong");

Comment: @Lirik check using `==` instead of `===`

Comment: same result, sorry
The odd part again is, when i add 'document.Slide' & 'document.IMG1', it seems to function however it will once again only run through the if statement, the ELSE IF will be ignored